# How to avoid g++ compiler bug on OS X?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I've been coding a solution for one problem on SPOJ.com website. It's this one:
http://www.spoj.com/problems/MINMOVE/

My solution was to create rolling hash for s+s (if s is full string from input), so I can get all rotations.

Here's the code:
https://github.com/vfonic/SPOJ/blob/master/minmove.cpp

I was testing locally and my code was failing on following simple test case:
aaba

It was printing 0 instead of 3 (3 is the number of rotations to get the lexicographically smallest string: aaab).

I added printf(" "); line as the [first line in h()](https://github.com/vfonic/SPOJ/blob/master/minmove.cpp#L30) function and, instead of 0, I got correct answer: 3.

I then removed the printf line and sent the code to SPOJ. My solution was accepted.
I also tested the same code (without printf) on my roommates' computer (Ubuntu) and he got 3.

I have latest OS X Mountain Lion: 10.8.4.
Here's the output of `g++ --version`:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Does anyone have any ideas why my code prints correct answer when I add dummy printf, and wrong answer otherwise?

Comment: It is most likely some undefined behaviour in your code. However, that version of GCC is ancient. I suggest cross-checking with a newer version (I used to get them from macports.org).

Comment: Have you checked that the indexes you use in the function are correct?

Comment: You'e using veryyyyyyyyyyy old version of GCC.

Comment: Oh, its simple, just download the (latest) source, and review it, and remove all bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I updated GCC version and it works flawlessly now. Thank you!